# CodeIgniter incorrect system path on private server

Tags: php, xampp, codeigniter-2

codeigniter project when uploaded to server gives me the following error.

> Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please
>   open the following file and correct this: index.php

it is **working well locally** & on **000webhost.com** hosting.

> When uploaded to private server of parallels it gives the above error.

My index.php is as follows.

```
<?php
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        error_reporting(0);
    break;

    default:
        exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
}
 }
$system_path = 'system';
$application_folder = 'application';


if (defined('STDIN'))
{
    chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
}

if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE)
{
    $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
}

$system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
{
    exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
}

define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
define('EXT', '.php');

// Path to the system folder
define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

// Name of the "system folder"
define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


// The path to the "application" folder
if (is_dir($application_folder))
{
    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
}
else
{
    if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
    {
        exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
    }

    define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
}
 require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

Comment: And what is your file/folder structure?

Comment: can u please provide the .htaccess you used.

Answer (score 1):

try this .htaccess on root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

assumming that **index.php** is your index page.

and change in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't go to mess with .htaccess,
actually before going to do that, as it's suggested in the above post,
I tried its later part, which is changing the

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

To the following

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And it simply worked for me!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Edit to add some more information ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

My CodeIgniter Directory structure:

```
htdocs /
       |_ CI /
             |_ OnlineStoreApp /
                               |_ online_store_ci  // This is the CodeIgniter folder
                               |_ public_html /
                                              |_ css
                                              |_ js
                                              |_ fonts
                                              |_ .htaccess // see bellow for more details
                                              |_ index.php // see bellow for more details
```

And my .htaccess file contains the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My `index.php` file is the same one provided by CodeIgniter root folder, but I have to change two lines in it as I place it inside the **public_html** directory instead of it's original place:

**Note:** look for the following two lines within the `index.php`,
 - `$system_path`
 - `$application_folder`
They have been edited, to point the locations, where `system` directory and `application` directory reside in.

```
<?php

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * You can load different configurations depending on your
 * current environment. Setting the environment also influences
 * things like logging and error reporting.
 *
 * This can be set to anything, but default usage is:
 *
 *     development
 *     testing
 *     production
 *
 * NOTE: If you change these, also change the error_reporting() code below
 *
 */
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Different environments will require different levels of error reporting.
 * By default development will show errors but testing and live will hide them.
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
 * as this file.
 *
 */
    $system_path = '../online_store_ci/system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 *
 */
    $application_folder = '../online_store_ci/application';

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * DEFAULT CONTROLLER
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file.
 * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a
 * specific controller class/function here.  For most applications, you
 * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those
 * special instances where you might want to override the standard
 * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation.
 *
 * IMPORTANT:  If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be
 * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE
 * specific controller.  Leave the function name blank if you need
 * to call functions dynamically via the URI.
 *
 * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" folder.  Leave blank
    // if your controller is not in a sub-folder within the "controllers" folder
    // $routing['directory'] = '';

    // The controller class file name.  Example:  Mycontroller
    // $routing['controller'] = '';

    // The controller function you wish to be called.
    // $routing['function'] = '';


/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 *
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';



// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS.  DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Resolve the system path for increased reliability
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
    }

    // ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // The PHP file extension
    // this global constant is deprecated.
    define('EXT', '.php');

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
        {
            exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
    }

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * And away we go...
 *
 */
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

Hope this might help somebody out there!

CodeIgniter Rocks!

Answer (score 1):

If you upload your project, follow these steps:

1. Make sure you have uploaded **application**, **system**, **index.php**, **.htaccess**
2. Modify your `config/database.php` with your hosted database.
3. Make sure you check your URL spellings, because Linux hosting is case-sensitive.
4. Make sure all resources are uploaded to server (CSS, JS, images, etc ...)

Comment: where can i find config/database.php

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue then i create controller inside that i have created index method then call cron file with below command it is working for me.

```
wget domain_name/google_script -O /dev/null

google_script = "My controller class name"
```

this solution work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');`
to

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '192.168.0.1' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost')
{
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
}
else
{
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
}
```

It worked for me.

Reference from [here](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-56102.html)