# codeigniter application on google app engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I am trying to move a codeigniter application to google app engine.I am using the google app engine launcher to deploy my app.The app seems to load on the localhost as it is throwing me a database error.(I have not connected yet to database ).The following is the output of the app on localhost.

> A Database Error Occurred.Unable to connect to your database server
>   using the provided settings.

But when i deployed the app on live server (google app engine) the app was throwing a diffrent error .

> Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly.
>   Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

The following is my app.yaml for codeignitor

```
application: wantroltd
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:

- url: /application/*
static_dir: application

- url: /install/*
static_dir: install

- url: /install/*
script: index.php

- url: /(.+\.php)$
script: \1

- url: ./*
script: index.php
```

I tried changing the application path to **'./application'** and even tried keeping it blank ,but it does not resolve my error .
Also my Application folder and index.php are in the same folder and the deployment was successful.What wrong am i doing ?

Comment: Your last handler should have have the url `/.*` not `./*`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Mars . I did change the handler but stil getting the same error

Comment: Can you post the content of your index.php?

Comment: You probably want to check this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309468/you-have-specified-an-invalid-database-connection-group-codeigniter-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a codeignitor error related to your routes being incorrect. I would make sure you really understand how codeignitor works in terms of where it expects files to be, and I would double-check that you understand how the [app.yaml configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig) works to make sure this aligns with what codeignitor is expecting.

[The issue here seems very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128063/codeigniter-incorrect-system-path-on-private-server). You can compare with knowledge of apache's htaccess file to see if your error is the same, but with app.yaml insead of .htaccess.